# React.js - is changing an uncontrolled input of type submit to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js currently.

I have get this warning despite I have effectively enter the value of my element in my component.state .

The objective is to trigger a disable version of my button, then an enable version of my button when the form is filled. So two version of button for each case. Hope makes sense.

Here my code :

component.state :

```
this.state= {nameSubmit: "offSubmit"}
```

component.form.element :

```
 <div>
      {formFilled ? (
       <input className="formLabel"  type="submit" name={this.state.nameSubmit || "" } value={this.state.nameSubmit || ""}/>
      ) : (
        <input className="formLabel"  type="submit" name={this.state.nameSubmit || ""} defaultValue={this.state.nameSubmit || ""}/>
      )}
    </div>
```

When my "formFilled" element pass to true the component is triggered in a operable version as :

`this.setState({nameSubmit: "onSubmit"})`.

But at this very moment my console returns me :

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input
>   of type submit to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from
>   uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a
>   controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

It seems to me I control hardly my form's element, I even use the state to determine all the value for test purposes. so I can't figure out what's going wrong on my code

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please, argument, because it's not in your question what's the way you're expecting it to work

Comment: The warning is being quite clear,  take a time to read and understand React documentation about [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)